# Delete text and other elements before and after the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to delete everything (text and other elements) before and after the element `<a>` with value class `chatlink`.
All this, within each element `<div>` with value class `main`.

**But only if `<div>` element with the value `main` contains a link with the value of `chatlink`.**

For example:

```
<div class="main">
    Bla bla bla :)
    <a href="#" class="chatlink"><img src="#" /></a>
    bla bla bla ...
    <a href="#" class="chatlink"><img src="#" /></a>
    tra la la la laaa
    <a href="#" class="postlink">some text</a>
    tralalaaa
</div>
```

Final code:

```
<div class="main">
    <a href="#" class="chatlink"><img src="#" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="chatlink"><img src="#" /></a>
</div>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I thank everyone for the answers.

Comment: Damn, I forgot one important thing. Do this only if `<div>` element with the value `main` contains a link with the value of `chatlink` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for all the text node within `.main` container using `filter()` and use `remove()` to remove them from the container or dom.

```
$('div.main:has(.chatlink)').contents().filter(function(){
   return this.nodeType == 3 || !$(this).hasClass('chatlink');
}).remove();​
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/Amjaq/3/

Note that I am using [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method on `$('.main')` which gets the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes. If you use any other find mechanism then textnodes are not considered.

Comment: "I need to delete everything (text **and other elements**)". I'll agree that the title is misleading, but there's not really any excuse for not reading the question properly.

Comment: But I also need to delete links and other elements that do not value class "chatlink".

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - I hear you, thanks for that. I edited my answer.

Comment: This is better? Ok, I use this.

Comment: This works as long as there are no non-<div> nodes with class=main, and all of the a.chatlink nodes you want to save are direct children of said div.main nodes.  Changing the '.main' selector to 'div.main' to eliminate the first caveat.

Comment: It would be possible to add a condition - only if <div> element with the value "main" contains a link with the value of "chatlink"?

Comment: @Edoras - Updated my answer based on your requirement.

Answer (score 5):

**Updated: and sorry for not understanding it correctly at the beginning**

use the following code:

for readability

```
$("div.main").each(function(){
        var currentDiv = $(this);
        var myLinks = $("a.chatlink", currentDiv);
        currentDiv.html(myLinks);
    })
```

quick with no intermediate variables

```
$("#btnClick").click(function(){
    $("div.main").each(function(){
        $(this).html($("a.chatlink", $(this)));
    })
  });
```

Here is an **updated** working demo http://jsfiddle.net/Xxwt9/7/

Comment: His use of `class="main"` instead of `id="main"` implies there are several of them.  Your proposed solution would make a proper mess in that case.

Comment: You'd want to be "div.main" and "a.chatlink" rather than just ".main" and ".chatlink" - and you need to make sure that you're not catching chatlink links that are outside of "div.main".  Also, I'd suggest using moves whenever possible, rather than clones.  Certain dynamic jquery behaviors get a little wonky with cloning.  Deestan's issue could then be fixed by hitting each of the divs individually with .each().

Comment: @Deestan: I've updated my proposed solution to take care of multiple divs

Comment: Also, you might want to change your 3rd line to something like "var mylinks = currentDiv.find('a.chatlink');" - I'm not quite sure what your current line does, but I don't think it's quite right.

Comment: @BenBarden: actually this is a correct syntax. jQuery $ accepts a 2nd parameter to define the scope on which the selector should run. it's the same as your suggested code, but with different syntax :).

Comment: Ah?  That's cool.  Thanks for the info.  Worth noting that the OP has added another requirement.

Comment: @MohammedElSayed Much better.  :-)  Downvote changed to upvote.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.  I believe the answer would be something like the following (though I may get it a bit wrong)

```
$("div.main").contents().not("a.chatlink").remove()
```

this assumes it is as you listed above, and all of the a tags you want to preserve are direct children of the div tags.  It grabs all children of the div tags, unselects those that are a with chatlink class, and removes the rest from the DOM.

edit: changed from children() to contents() based on Shankar's correction.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way

```
var links=$('.main a')​;
$('.main').html(links);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uNaQY/) is a fiddle.

Comment: With `$('.main a.chatlink')​;` that it works exactly as I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: It is always better to remove what you don't need than DOM manipulation.

Comment: this will not work if there are more than .main div inside your page. also this will get all the links, not just .chatlinks

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$( '.main' ).contents().remove( ':not(.chatlink)' );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/wrUuw/

Answer (score -1):

Select the elements you want to keep, detach them, empty the div, then reattach them.

```
var chatlinks = $(".main a.chatlink").detach();
$(".main").empty().append(chatlinks);
```

Comment: Selector `.main a.chatlink` is incorrect - captures deeper child nodes than specified.  Should be `.main > a.chatlink`.

Comment: @Deestan he did not specify that all children would be direct children or that there would be multiple `.main` divs. Additionally, the question was modified after I posted my answer.